# Saving Model Causes Failed Invalidation in has_many / belongs_to Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord, model

I have two models:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base

   has_many :orders

end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

   belongs_to :customer
   validates :customer, presence: true

end
```

I get a validation error if I do the following:

```
$ customer = Customer.new()
$ order = Order.new()
$ customer.orders << order
$ order.save!
```

Why does this cause the following validation error:

> Validation failed: Order is invalid

If I instead save the customer:

```
$ customer = Customer.new()
$ order = Order.new()
$ customer.orders << order
$ customer.save!
```

I get the error:

> Validation failed: Customer can't be blank

What is going on? Should I not be validation an `belongs_to` relationship?

Comment: You need to save your order before you save the customer

Comment: @MrYoshiji  But as I state in my question, saving the order causes an invalidation error: 'Validation failed: Order is invalid' because at this point the order's customer association is nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get around this issue, use `inverse_of` on both end of the association.

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, inverse_of: :customer
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer, inverse_of: :orders

  validates :customer, presence: true
end
```

Then you should be able to do the following

```
>> customer = Customer.new
>> customer.orders << Order.new
>> customer.save! # should create both customer and order
```

Comment: Anybody know if this is still true as of Rails 4.1.8?